# Aligning Elements to Elements in a different ConstraintLayout

Tags: android

I am currently familiarizing myself with the new `ConstraintLayout`, and try to combine them with card views, but have hit a road block while trying to align elements between two `CardView`s.

I want to align in this picture

- the heart pictogram with the armor class
- the 5 with initative with the Initiative
- the 10 with the speed

[image: The current status]

But I cannot seem to accomplish this. Here is what I tried:

```
ConstraintLayout
   -CardView
       -ArmorClassTextView
       -...
   -CardView
       -HitPointView
       -...
```

This does not work because the Constraints added to the nested elements seem to get ignored.

```
LinearLayout
    -CardView
        -ConstraintLayout
            -ArmorClassTextView
            -...
    -CardView
        -ConstraintLayout
            -HitPointView
            -...
```

Here, the HitPointView can be aligned to other elements in its ConstraintLayout, but not to elements from the other one. If I try, I get an error stating that the referenced element is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout.

Can you please give me a hint as to how to accomplish this type of alignment? I have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not working for a good reason: all that ConstraintLayout sees (what it can layout) are its direct children (like any other layout, in fact). That's why you cannot set up a constraint across those two card views, as the card views are the only elements you could apply a constraint to in this case.

Now, in the future there are a few things we are thinking of implementing that might help with this scenario (virtual view groups, draw elements..). But that's for future versions of ConstraintLayout, so that's not really helpful to you just right now :)

That said, there are a couple of things you could do today as a workaround:

- If using two ConstraintLayout, you might want to add vertical guidelines and create them identically in both layouts; then constraint the internal elements to those guidelines. Specifically, you can create two vertical guidelines at a relative position of 33% and 66% in order to basically create 3 columns, then center elements by connecting each side: | <- A -> **|** <- B -> **|** <- C -> | . Then replicate that setup for your second cardview. Not great, but might be easier to maintain.
- Use a single ConstraintLayout, but instead of setting the elements *inside* a cardview, move them out of it. Declare the cardviews at the beginning of the xml, then the widgets. Constrain the cardviews to the widget in a way that they will correctly resize (using 0dp)

Comment: I tried to follow your second advice - single ConstraintLayout with CardView which wraps a widget using 0dp. But regardless of the order in XML, the CardView is always drawn on top of the widget. Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/davidvavra/c266757113eced899e6a598281fa561e